# jemandem etwas lernen?

Tags: grammaticality

Ich höre und lese gelegentlich *jemandem etwas lernen*, offensichtlich in der Bedeutung *jemanden etwas lehren*, z. B. in dieser Form:

> Eltern [...] haben die Pflicht, ihren Kindern [...] schwimmen zu lernen.

Quelle: [Spiegel Online Forum](http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/schule/schwimmkurs-wann-kinder-schwimmen-lernen-sollten-a-1150884.html#js-article-comments-box-pager)

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lernen) kennt diese Bedeutung nicht.

Daher meine Frage, wie gängig diese Form ist und ob sie von anderer Stelle als korrekt angesehen wird?

Comment: Zumindest in Bayern oft gehört; dort aber in der Regel als umgangssprachlich verstanden.

Comment: Gibt's auch hier in Berlin.

Comment: Wer das beim Spiegel schreibt dem gehören die Löffel langgezogen, das ist ja gruselig.

Comment: In vielen schweizerdeutschen Dialekten verwendet man für lernen und lehren dasselbe Wort "lehre".

Comment: Die Lehrerin meiner Tochter sagt das, habe eben danach gegoogelt. Nun wissen wir Bescheid und unsere Tochter wird sie nun künftig mit "Guten Tag Frau Lernerin" begrüßen. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In meinem *»Duden - Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache (2000)«* steht im Eintrag **lernen** als dritte Bedeutung:

> **3.** (in landschaftlicher Umgangssprache, hochsprachlich nicht korrekt) *lehren*: Eine andere Nachbarin kam, um mir das Kochen und Flicken zu lernen.
>   (Wimschneider, Herbstmilch 9); Der (=der Lehrer) hat uns ... das
>   Telefonieren gelernt (Kempowski, Immer 52)

Comment: Überraschenderweise verzeichnet jedoch *Duden Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* diese dialektale Bedeutungs- und Verwendungsvariante nicht - weder in der 2. Auflage (1989, 1816 Seiten) noch in der 8. Auflage (2015, 2118 Seiten).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich habe beide Bücher und kann vergleichen; das Universalwörterbuch hat einen deutlich geringeren Umfang, erkennbar auch am [Preis](http://www.duden.de/Shop/Duden-Das-gro%C3%9Fe-W%C3%B6rterbuch-der-deutschen-Sprache-0).

Comment: Ja, gut... oder eben die Seitenzahl. Insofern auch wieder nicht überraschenderweise.

Comment: Jetzt habe ich mir wieder etwas gelernt :-)

Answer (score 4):

> <strike>Jemandem etwas lernen</strike>

ist nach den Regeln der deutschen Standardsprache nicht richtig. Es kommt allerdings in einigen Dialekten in der Praxis recht häufig vor.

Standard- und schriftsprachlich richtig ist

> Jemanden etwas lehren. (Jemanden das Schwimmen lehren. Jemanden das Fürchten lehren.)
>
> Jemandem etwas beibringen.

Für deinen Beispielsatz mit den Eltern und dem Schwimmen wären also u.a. folgende Varianten akzeptabel:

> Eltern haben die Pflicht, ihren Kindern schwimmen beizubringen.
>
> Eltern haben die Pflicht, ihren Kindern das Schwimmen beibringen zu lassen.
>
> Eltern haben die Pflicht, ihre Kinder schwimmen lernen zu lassen.
>
> Eltern haben die Pflicht, ihre Kinder schwimmen zu lehren.

Der letzte Satz legt allerdings die Deutung nahe, dass die Eltern das Lehren  persönlich übernehmen sollten. Er mag in den üblichen Kontexten also unpassend sein.

Comment: Der erste Absatz beantwortet die Frage, allerdings ohne Quellen oder Details. Der Rest ist absolut überflüssig.

Comment: @CarstenS Die meisten Antworten enthalten Überflüssiges. Insofern ist auch Dein Kommentar überflüssig - und meiner genauso ;-)